# Creating an Access form that allows me to select a user (from Table1) and display results (from Table2) that have a key coinciding with that user

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I don't know how to ask the question such that I can find an answer.

I'm trying to create a form that can allow me to select a person from one table. The table contains `SSN`, and `First`, `Last`, `Middle` names. I have that part working.

What I don't yet understand how to do is then populate a group of textboxes and labels on the form with the column headers of a second table.

It should populate with everything but the `ID` and `SSN` fields and put that person's information (a selection of dates) in the text boxes to be edited.

Sadly, I've already accomplished this in *Excel*, but due to runtime issues, I'm trying to port it over to *Access*, since the dataset is getting larger daily, and *Excel* is no longer well suited for the task.

I don't have enough rep to post an image into this post, so please go here to see a [visual representation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z--jT43KWtQzBtbjNTWmFwSFU/view?usp=sharing) of what I'm talking about.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the list of header, you could loop through the RecordSet field name: `rst.Fields(n).Name` of a `Select *` query of you table.

You could then use the field selected by the user to build a second query for you last column that match the good user and the right header such has:

```
StrSql = " Select " & MySelectedField & " From MyTable where userID = " & MySelectedUser &";"
```

Hope this helps!